# OpenERP 7 tree view doesn't show search box and other filters

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

I have created a tree view to extend account.invoice module with a list with custom and special columns. I am trying to insert a search view but it is no working (I can show data in tree view but not the search box and other filters I need).

XML:

```
<openerp>
   <data>
      <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_account_invoices_resume_list">
         <field name="name">account.invoice.resume.tree</field>
         <field name="model">account.invoice.resume</field>
         <field name="type">tree</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Invoices list">
               <field name="date_invoice"/>
               <field name="number"/>
               <field name="partner_id"/>
               <field name="inv_vat"/>
               <field name="tax_base_0"/>
               <field name="tax_base_4"/>
               <field name="tax_base_10"/>
               <field name="tax_base_21"/>
               <field name="tax_iva_4"/>
               <field name="tax_iva_10"/>
               <field name="tax_iva_21"/>
               <field name="amount_total" sum="Total Amount"/>
            </tree>
         </field>
      </record>
      <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_account_invoices_resume_search">
         <field name="name">account.invoice.resume.search</field>
         <field name="model">account.invoice.resume</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Filtrado de facturas">
               <field name="date_invoice_from" filter_domain="[('date_invoice','>=',self)]"/>
               <field name="date_invoice_to" filter_domain="[('date_invoice','<=',self)]"/>
            </search>
         </field>
      </record>
      <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_account_invoices_resume_list_tree">
         <field name="name">Facturas para gestoría</field>
         <field name="res_model">account.invoice.resume</field>
         <field name="view_type">form</field><field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
         <field name="view_id" ref="view_account_invoices_resume_search"/>
         <field name="domain">[('type','=','out_invoice'),('state','in',['open','paid'])]</field>
      </record>
      <menuitem id="menu_invoices_for_closure_list_client" name="Facturas de clientes para gestoría" parent="account.menu_finance_receivables" sequence="10" action="action_account_invoices_resume_list_tree"/>
   </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, *view_id* reference to tree,form,kanban... etc

If we want to add search view for object then we need to register search view id in *search_view_id*

Try with following code.

Replace line

```
<field name="view_id" ref="view_account_invoices_resume_search"/>
```

with

```
<field name="view_id" ref="view_account_invoices_resume_list"/>
<field name="search_view_id" ref="view_account_invoices_resume_search"/>
```

**EDIT**

Replace line

```
<field name="domain">[('type','=','out_invoice'),('state','in',['open','paid'])]</field>
```

with

```
<field name="domain">[('type','=','out_invoice'),('state','in',('open','paid'))]</field>
```

Add `state` field in your tree view.

Afterwards, restart server and upgrade your module.

Comment: It works! Thank you, @Odedra.

Now, I'm having an error on tree view: _Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.rows']: Runtime Error: Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.row']: Runtime Error: Error: Unknown field state in domain [["state","not in",["draft"]]]_

In XML I wrote: `<field name="domain">[('type','=','out_invoice'),('state','in',['open','paid'])]</field>`

Comment: I have already solved: [https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/4430] Have a nice day!